# The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: android, animation, overriding

I tried to add animation on start activity intent and I got this error. It's the first time I've seen something like this, I looked up on google and SO but I was unable to find anything that would help me solve this issue.
So how can I fix this? Whats wrong with my code?

```
holder.transfer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int clickedposition = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Intent iv = new Intent(context,
                    MenuActivity.class);

            if (iv != null) {
                iv.putExtra("NAME", ringNames[position]);
                int [] res = songPos;
                iv.putExtra("PATH", res[position]);
                iv.putExtra("FILE", ringNames[position]+".mp3");
                ((Activity) context).startActivity(iv);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
            }

                 try
                  {
                    CentralActivity.playing = Boolean.valueOf(false);
                    CentralActivity.mp.stop();
                    CentralActivity.mp.release();

                    return;
                  }
                  catch (Exception localException)
                  {

                  }

        }
    });
```

I get error The method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
```

with:

```
 ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
```

You need to call the method `overridePendingTransition` from an activity, but you do it in a `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin**, **SDK >= 33** this method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
   val options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(baseContext, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
   startActivity(intentLevel, options.toBundle())
} else {
    startActivity(intentLevel)
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent iv = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this
                    MenuActivity.class);

if (iv != null) {
    iv.putExtra("NAME", ringNames[position]);
    int [] res = songPos;
    iv.putExtra("PATH", res[position]);
    iv.putExtra("FILE", ringNames[position]+".mp3");
    startActivity(iv);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
}
```